# Is this true or false: Switching two columns of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ doesn't change $det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}.$
>
> True or false? Switching two columns of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times
> n}$ doesn't change $det(A)$. State why.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, then $det(A)=-1$

Now switching first column with second column, we have $A'=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, then $det(A')=1$

In this example, we saw that the determinant changed, thus the statement is wrong.

---

Did I do it correctly and is the reasoning correct? Is there a better, more general / valid reasoning?

Comment: The solution is perfect. You thought the statement was false, and you showed this by finding an explicit counterexample.

Comment: note that you can't change the absolute value of $\det A$ by switching columns or rows.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth I'll add that it's usually easier to try to find the **simplest** counterexamples. For instance, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ would have worked, and its determinant is much easier to compute

Comment: In fact, swapping any two rows or any two columns multiplies the determinant by $-1$. It might be helpful to compute the determinant of a few permutation matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false in general. It would be enough to think about the identity matrix.

However, if $A$ is not of full rank, then switching two columns would not change the determinant.

Answer (score 2):

To be more general there is a result that says $\det (A\cdot B) = \det A \cdot \det B$.

You can write a column switch as a matrixmultiplication.

**small example:**
\begin{align}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a&b&c \\ d&f&g \\ h&i&j
\end{matrix}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a&c&b \\ d&g&f \\ h&j&i
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{align}
the determinate of the switching matrix is always $-1$ if you want to switch more than $1$ column then the determinate will be $\pm 1$ but the absolute value of the determinate of a switching matrix will alway be $+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Think of cross product of vectors, as position of vectors are interchanged direction of product vector is opposite.